# Installing packages and drivers from a flash drive on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have a server with Ubuntu 18.04 installed and it does not have access to the internet. How would I install external drivers and programs if I cannot use  `sudo apt get`  etc..?

Answer (score 0):

You can download Ubuntu packages from:
packages.ubuntu.com
and install them with dpkg.
If you get a error message telling you to first install dependencies then you can download them and install them as well. If you have a server with Internet access that has the same version of Ubuntu and the same software as the offline server, you can run apt-get on that server to see what dependencies are needed without actually installing the software.
If you have downloaded drivers, you should read the README files to see how to install the drivers manually.